# SQLITE: Create View to multiple tables via index

Tags: sql, sqlite

Presently I am writting a bit of code for logging requests into a sqlite database.
To get the database to be not so bloated up I am using different tables containing the invariant data(`apps`,`machineID`,`ips` and `platforms`) which can appear a lot of times, but are very often unique and the main table (`access`) just keeps references on rows in the other tables by their ids. Now I want to create a view that shows the main data from the other tables instead of the indexes to the other tables.

Example for my tables:

```
apps Table
----------
id      application     buildNum
1       app1            24.112
2       app2            24.113

machineID Table
--------------
id      machineID
1       12345
2       1235

ips Table
---------
id      ip
1       192.168.9.53

platforms Table
---------------
id      platform        os
1       windows         win7
2       windows         win8

access Table
------------
date            ip_id   machineID_id    platform_id     application_id  responseCode
1391677790.7363 1       1               1               1               404
1391677797.5792 1       1               1               1               404
1391677800.7379 1       2               2               2               404
1391677802.493  1       2               2               2               404
1391677889.7193 1       1               1               1               404
1391677890.6034 1       2               2               2               404
```

Now I would like to create a view that looks like this:

```
date            ip            machineID       platform   os       application  buildNum   responseCode
1391677790.7363 192.168.9.53  12345           windows    win7     app1         24.112     404
1391677797.5792 192.168.9.53  12345           windows    win7     app1         24.112     404
1391677800.7379 192.168.9.53  1235            windows    win8     app2         24.113     404
1391677802.493  192.168.9.53  1235            windows    win8     app2         24.113     404
1391677889.7193 192.168.9.53  12345           windows    win7     app1         24.112     404
1391677890.6034 192.168.9.53  1235            windows    win8     app2         24.113     404
```

Any clues on how to do this with Sqlite. Sorry if this might look like a novice question, but I am not so familiar with SQL.

Here would be the code for setting up the example tables:

```sqlite
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE ips (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ip TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO "ips" VALUES(1,'192.168.9.53');
CREATE TABLE platforms (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,platform TEXT NOT NULL,os TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE(platform,os));
INSERT INTO "platforms" VALUES(1,'windows','win7');
INSERT INTO "platforms" VALUES(2,'windows','win8');
CREATE TABLE apps (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,application TEXT NOT NULL,buildNum TEXT not null, UNIQUE(application,buildNum));
INSERT INTO "apps" VALUES(1,'app1','24.112');
INSERT INTO "apps" VALUES(2,'app2','24.113');
CREATE TABLE machineIDs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,machineID TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO "machineIDs" VALUES(1,'12345');
INSERT INTO "machineIDs" VALUES(2,'1235');
CREATE TABLE access (date REAL PRIMERY KEY DEFAULT ((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400.0),ip_id INTEGER NOT NULL,machineID_id INTEGER,platform_id INTEGER,application_id INTEGER,responseCode INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677790.7363,1,1,1,1,404);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677797.5792,1,1,1,1,404);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677800.7379,1,2,2,2,404);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677802.493,1,2,2,2,404);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677889.7193,1,1,1,1,404);
INSERT INTO "access" VALUES(1391677890.6034,1,2,2,2,404);
COMMIT;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should study the JOIN command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT access.date, ips.ip, machineIDs.machineID, platforms.platform, platforms.os, apps.application, apps.buildNum, access.responseCode 
FROM access
    LEFT JOIN ips ON access.ip_id = ips.id
    LEFT JOIN machineIDs ON access.machineID_id = machineIDs.id 
    LEFT JOIN platforms ON access.platform_id = platforms.id
    LEFT JOIN apps ON access.application_id = apps.id
```

Comment: Maybe add some explaining words: Why specifically using `LEFT JOIN`?